# How to secure an aspx page called by Flex?

Tags: asp.net, apache-flex, security

How can I secure an aspx page that is called by a Flex application of ours? It has to be secured for the whole application, not for particular users.

Is it possible to give credentials with the Flex Call? In Asp.net, only some five aspx pages need to be secured. The amf calls are already secured.

I do not want a popup to be displayed when Flex calls the page. The users are not in Active Directory, so they wouldn't be able to log in.

Examples of aspx pages we use from Flex are aspx pages to load media, to get an export of data in csv format, to upload media, ...

Comment: Are the users required to enter credentials when to log on the flex app? The aspx page are called from within the app?

Comment: Yes, users are required to enter credentials, so I could send the credentials just as post data, and then check the credentials. But I was wondering if there was another way.

Comment: Have you looked at sending the credentials from ASPX to Flex via Javascript?

Comment: Could you also elaborate on what you're trying to do?  I have a few ideas.